# SpringMVC exception message not returned to client

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, client-server

My SpringMVC code has an exception handler, something like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleSomeException(SomeException e)
{
    logExceptionMessage(e);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("custom message", 401);
}
```

I am reading the code on the client, something like:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contentStream, "UTF-8"));
```

The exception is a simple subclass of:

```
public class SomeException extends RuntimeException
{
    public SomeException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public SomeException(String message, Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public SomeException(Throwable cause)
    {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

When there are no server errors, everything works fine.

When the server throws the exception handler, the client is correctly receiving the error status code (in this case 401) but instead of returning the custom error message, it is returning

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://myUrl.json
```

How can I get the custom error message??

Comment: Do you have @ControllerAdvice annotation?

Comment: May be your custom exception handler is not handling the exception thrown by the server, so it is passed on to the default java exception handling mechanism.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad But it is returning the correct HTTP code. I showed 401 above but it actually returns whatever http status that I set. I showed the handler in my posting, is there something else I need to be doing?

Comment: @victor grazi, please upload your SomeException.java class

Comment: @RohitGaikwad I added it to the posting

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue, I was looking at the error message in the thrown exception.
If I explicitly read the actual message I can see the server message:

```
private static String getErrorMessage(HttpURLConnection connection)
{
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader;
    try (InputStream errorStream = connection.getErrorStream())
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream));
        while (true)
        {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            } else
            {
                message.append(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.warn("Error reading server error message", e);
    }
    return message.toString();
}
```

I don't know if there is a more concise way (using Java 7), but this is working for me